# Protect the font format in macros

Tags: fonts, macros

I define a macro (\chit) that uses one font (sc), and the macro is used in another macro that textbf in the implementation - `\textbf{Q\thequestion: #1?}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcounter{question}

\newcommand{\chit}{\textsc{Chitx}\xspace}
\newcommand\Que[1]{%
    \leavevmode\par
    \stepcounter{question}
    \noindent
    \textbf{Q\thequestion: #1?}\par}

\newcommand\Ans[1]{%
     \leavevmode\par\noindent
    {\textbf{A\thequestion:} #1\par}}

\begin{document}

\Que{What is \chit}? % <-- Wrong font
What is \chit? % <-- Correct font

\end{document}
```

As a result, the output does not show the font type that I expected. 
How to protect the font type that I specified in the \chit macro?

[image]

### EDIT1

For the Q&A macro, I copied it from [Q&A Template in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54260/qa-template-in-latex)

Comment: what is the intention of `\leavevmode\par\noindent` ? It's a rather strange construct!

Comment: @David: I just copied them from other question. I updated the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/bx/n' instead on input line 19.
```

which means that there is no boldface small caps font in the Computer Modern font family.

On the other hand, the European Modern font family does have it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcounter{question}

\newcommand{\chit}{\textsc{Chitx}\xspace}
\newcommand\Que[1]{%
    \leavevmode\par
    \stepcounter{question}%
    \noindent
    \textbf{Q\thequestion: #1?}\par}

\newcommand\Ans[1]{%
     \leavevmode\par\noindent
    {\textbf{A\thequestion:} #1\par}}

\begin{document}

\Que{What is \chit}? % <-- Wrong font
What is \chit? % <-- Correct font

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure what `\leavevmode\par` is for; if your aim is to have some space before the question, it's the wrong tool:

```
\newcommand\Que[1]{%
    \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}% <--- or whatever
    \noindent\stepcounter{question}
    \textbf{Q\thequestion: #1?}\par
}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcounter{question}

\newcommand{\chit}{\textsc{Chitx}}
\newcommand\Que[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}% <---- fix it
  \noindent\stepcounter{question}%
  \textbf{Q\thequestion: #1?}\par
}

\newcommand\Ans[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \textbf{A\thequestion:}~#1\par
}

\begin{document}

Some text before the question. What is \chit?

\Que{What is \chit}
\Ans{I don't know}

\end{document}
```

[image]