# Numbering a Large Number of Questions

Tags: numbering

I am writing a book and a common problem is that when I am numbering my questions I write a list and find myself having to go back and renumber all the problems. It is weird but this site auto-corrects it for some reason (there might be a package being used that I do not have).  For example, let's say I had a list of a ninety nine problems.

1. Problem 1 Writing
2. Problem 2 Writing
3. Problem 3 Writing
4. Problem 4 Writing...

and then I realized that I should have put a problem between one and two. Is there a way to create an ongoing list so that way I do not have to renumber all the problems?

Comment: almost every latex construct numbers automatically, sections, theorems, problems, etc. What markup are you using that is _not_ getting numbered? It is hard to say what is wrong with your code if you do not show it.

Comment: Might be somewhat related: [Q&A Template in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54260/qa-template-in-latex)

Comment: I do not know what a markup is lol? Is it the use package stuff?

Comment: @andselisk I think that is what I need.

Comment: @W.G. I think you can adapt that template for your case then, and answer your own question:)

Comment: sorry by markup I just mean the latex commands that you had  used, so for example `\section{this}...\section{that}` makes sections 1 and 2 with no explicit numbers, but `\textbf{1 this}..\textbf{2 that}` has explicit numbers 1 and 2 (and is almost always wrong thing to do)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I figured it out, but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of the document write the following:

```
\newcounter{question}
\setcounter{question}{0}
\newcounter{answer}
\setcounter{answer}{0}
```

Also, type

```
\newcommand\que[1]{%
   \leavevmode\par
   \stepcounter{question}
   \noindent
   \thequestion. #1\par}.
```

Also, for `\ans{..}`, do the same thing.

Then, keep asking questions and answering them like such:

```
\que{Put question here}
\ans{Put answer here}
```

Comment: Well, you've left out the definitions of `\que` and `\ans`, so if anyone else  sees this, they might wonder where those macros came from. (Which is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54260/qa-template-in-latex, as I understand it.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I forgot to add that as well. Good catch!

Comment: If you ever plan to cross-reference one or more of the questions (using LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` system), you should change `\stepcounter` to `\refstepcounter` in the definition of `\que`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method I use for this is to treat these as a theorem-like construct.  An alternative, see below, is a list (`enumerate` construct).

## Theorem-like approach

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[section]
```

then provides you with an environment labelled "Problem #.##", `#` being the section number, and `##` being the problem number within that section.  You can then use the standard LaTeX `\label...\ref` mechanism to refer to problem numbers.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{problem}
  First problem
\end{problem}
Text.
\begin{problem}
  \label{prob:sec}
  Second problem
\end{problem}

\section{Second section}

\begin{problem}
  Third problem, but first in second section.
\end{problem}

Have a look at Problem~\ref{prob:sec}.

\end{document}
```

If you just want problems numbered consecutively throughout the document, then drop `[section]` from the `\newtheorem` command above.  If you want numbering within another unit such as chapter then replace `[section]` by `[chapter]` or whatever.

For ease of referencing consider using the `cleveref` package (load it last of all your packages).  The following produces the same output as above, but you just write `\cref` instead of `Problem~\ref`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{problem}
  First problem
\end{problem}
Text.
\begin{problem}
  \label{prob:sec}
  Second problem
\end{problem}

\section{Second section}

\begin{problem}
  Third problem, but first in second section.
\end{problem}

Have a look at \cref{prob:sec}.

\end{document}
```

## List approach

Using a standard enumerate, each problem can be just an `\item` and you can use the `\label...\ref` mechanism.

[image: Sample list]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Problems}
\begin{enumerate}
\item The first problem.
\item\label{prob:second} The second problem.
\item The third problem uses problem~\ref{prob:second}.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Of course, the numbering gets mixed up with ordinary lists.  To avoid that you can define dedicated environment with distinguished labels.

[image: More elaborate list]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{problems}{\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\thesection.\arabic{enumi}}\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{it:ord} Ordinary list item.
\end{enumerate}

\section{Problems}
\begin{problems}
\item The first problem.
\item\label{prob:second} The second problem.
\item The third problem uses problem~\ref{prob:second}.
\end{problems}

\section{Another section}

\begin{enumerate}
\item\label{it:ord2} Ordinary list item.
\end{enumerate}

Problem~\ref{prob:second} item~\ref{it:ord} and item~\ref{it:ord2}.

\end{document}
```